# Excel VBA, How to make a TextBox format only Date

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a textbox but that text box only can be input by date format and nothing else.

Comment: You can link the textbox to a cell in the worksheet and then format that cell as date. Just click on the text box. Type `=` in the formula bar and then click the target cell which should be formatted as Date.

Comment: not like that, i mean..
i made a userform that contains a textbox call date, i want the textbox can only be input by date format such as mm/dd/yyyy, and the user can't input any word in it..

Comment: do you mean a User_Form `TextBox` ? or an `InputBox` ?

Comment: user_form TextBox

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you can't (easily) force the text in a TextBox to always be a valid date, but you can check what has been entered as the user tries to leave the TextBox:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If Not IsDate(TextBox1.Text) Then
        MsgBox "Date required"
        Cancel = True
    End If
    'Display value in another textbox for testing purposes
    TextBox2.Text = Format(CDate(TextBox1.Text), "dd/mm/yyyy")
End Sub
```

Using `IsDate` will allow **any** system-recognised date to be entered, so you should use `CDate(TextBox1.Text)` to access the date entered.  Don't rely on the text itself being in a particular format because the text entered could be, for instance:

- `"08/03/2017"`
- `"8 March 2017"`
- `"8 Mar"`
- `"8/3/17"`

Comment: well actualy i have though about that format, so i made this 1 label that tell the user to only use format mm/dd/yyyy for the date textbox, if the users use another format then what i already tell, or they input a word in it, it'll pop up a msgbox...
i was already found a way but i forgot to save and i lost it, now i forgot what's the code...
i remember only it's has something to do with "dim a as date" and i forgot the rest...

Comment: @EkaOktavianus From a user-experience point of view, it is usually better to allow them to enter the date in whatever format they like - don't limit them to just one specific format.  Providing the program uses that date as a `Date`, all the program cares about is that it **is** a valid date.